# Can someone help me with one more relative XPath to find an element?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Sorry to ask again.

I have one more webElement I can't locate on an Angular grid. I can get the XPath but it's very long and I need to condense it.
FULL HTML and my XPath are below. I need to find one of the cell elements in the table.

I want to locate this

```
<td aria-describedby="dx-col-20" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="4" style="text-align: left;" tabindex="0" class="dx-cell-focus-disabled">Testie Tester</td>
```

See FULL HTML code below

```
<table class="dx-datagrid-table dx-datagrid-table-fixed" role="presentation"><colgroup><col style="width: 30px;"><col><col><col><col></colgroup><tbody role="presentation"><tr class="dx-row dx-data-row dx-row-lines dx-selection" role="row" aria-selected="true" aria-rowindex="1"><td aria-describedby="dx-col-17" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" class="grid-icon-container" tabindex="0" style="text-align: left;"><img class="grid-icon" src="/assets/app/document-types/DOC-Active-16x16.svg" alt="icon"></td><td aria-describedby="dx-col-18" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="2" style="text-align: left;"><a onclick="window.navEventUrl='customLink:/document/people/b20236e5-2802-4dd4-8ae0-47910099d34b/TestCv1.doc/6289d044-a9dc-45d4-ab40-80eb90d589db'; window.dispatchEvent(new Event('navEvent'))">TestCv1.doc</a></td><td aria-describedby="dx-col-19" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" style="text-align: left;">38912</td><td aria-describedby="dx-col-20" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="4" style="text-align: left;" tabindex="0" class="dx-cell-focus-disabled">Testie Tester</td><td aria-describedby="dx-col-21" aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="5" style="text-align: left;" title="21/05/2019 11:50:46 am">21/05/2019 11:50:46 am</td></tr><tr class="dx-row dx-freespace-row" role="presentation" style="height: 391px;"><td style="text-align: left;"></td><td style="text-align: left;"></td><td style="text-align: left;"></td><td style="text-align: left;"></td><td style="text-align: left;"></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

And my XPath (which does work) is

```
//*[@id="content-container"]/inv-sidebar-layout-content/ng-component/ng-component/section/div[2]/as-split/as-split-area[1]/article/inv-people-tabs/inv-vertical-tabs-list/div[2]/div/inv-tab[4]/div/inv-grid/div/div/div[2]/dx-data-grid/div/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]
```

Comment: we may require full html to determine xpath

Comment: try this `//td[1]/@role` or `/td[@aria-describedby="dx-col-21"]` .. may it help you

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately neither of those worked for me.

Comment: if you could provide more html that helps like starts from table element

Comment: Ok added more HTML, many thanks

Comment: Try this http://xpather.com/tRjNMaAs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below XPath worked for me, to select a line in the Angular grid, using Selenium (driver.FindElement)

```
 //*[@class='dx-row dx-data-row dx-row-lines']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following xpath you will get all the `<td>`

```
//table[@class="dx-datagrid-table dx-datagrid-table-fixed"]//tr//td
```

If you want get image from first cell try below xpath.

```
//table[@class="dx-datagrid-table dx-datagrid-table-fixed"]//tr//td/img[@class="grid-icon"]
```

if you want to get TestCv1.doc try below xpath

```
//table[@class="dx-datagrid-table dx-datagrid-table-fixed"]//tr//td/a[contains(.,"TestCv1.doc")]
```

if you want fetch testi tester use following xpath.

```
//table[@class="dx-datagrid-table dx-datagrid-table-fixed"]//tr//td[contains(.,"Testie Tester")]
```

if you want to fetch time.

```
//table[@class="dx-datagrid-table dx-datagrid-table-fixed"]//tr[1]//td[5]
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to get say the text from 4th cell.

Comment: just use index like `//table[@class="dx-datagrid-table dx-datagrid-table-fixed"]//tr[1]//td[5]`

Comment: Getting closer but for some reason, this is clicking the column header rather than the cell. I changed the index but it still doesn't work..

Comment: Instead of tr[1] use tr[2]

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already and the test failed saying index out of range exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193699/discussion-between-kunduk-and-rshome).